# Como publicar uma APK específica para versões do Android superiores a $API?

Tags: android, apache-cordova, google-play, apk

Tenho um aplicativo na Play Store que usa o plugin Crosswalk. Porém, para versões do Android de 5.0 para cima, quero poder disponibilizar uma *build* sem o *plugin* do Crosswalk. Ficando apenas as versões abaixo de 5.0 com a *build* que inclui o determinado *plugin*.

Comment: Como você fez para adicionar o Crosswalk ao projeto? O meu, mesmo achando que já está, quando roda pede pra baixar o crosswalk...  Obrigado.

Comment: @Ramos tem um plugin cordova do crosswalk

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de fazer isso é verificar a versão da *Build* dentro da sua aplicação utilizando  `android.os.Build.VERSION`, que é uma classe estática que contém várias informações sobre o sistema operacional Android.

#### Exemplo

```
// Verifica está em uso a versão Android 5.0 +
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // não usar o plugin Crosswalk.
} else {
    // usar o plugin Crosswalk.
}
```

[**`android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html):

```
SDK_INT value        Build.VERSION_CODES        Human Version Name       
    1                  BASE                      Android 1.0 (no codename)
    2                  BASE_1_1                  Android 1.1 Petit Four
    3                  CUPCAKE                   Android 1.5 Cupcake
    4                  DONUT                     Android 1.6 Donut
    5                  ECLAIR                    Android 2.0 Eclair
    6                  ECLAIR_0_1                Android 2.0.1 Eclair                  
    7                  ECLAIR_MR1                Android 2.1 Eclair
    8                  FROYO                     Android 2.2 Froyo
    9                  GINGERBREAD               Android 2.3 Gingerbread
   10                  GINGERBREAD_MR1           Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread
   11                  HONEYCOMB                 Android 3.0 Honeycomb
   12                  HONEYCOMB_MR1             Android 3.1 Honeycomb
   13                  HONEYCOMB_MR2             Android 3.2 Honeycomb
   14                  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH        Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich
   15                  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1    Android 4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich
   16                  JELLY_BEAN                Android 4.1 Jellybean
   17                  JELLY_BEAN_MR1            Android 4.2 Jellybean
   18                  JELLY_BEAN_MR2            Android 4.3 Jellybean
   19                  KITKAT                    Android 4.4 KitKat
   20                  KITKAT_WATCH              Android 4.4 KitKat Watch
   21                  LOLLIPOP                  Android 5.0 Lollipop
   22                  LOLLIPOP_MR1              Android 5.1 Lollipop
   23                  M                         Android 6.0 Marshmallow
   24                  N                         Android 7.0 Nougat
  10000                CUR_DEVELOPMENT           Current Development Build
```

#### Detalhes

- [Build.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Comment: esqueci de mencionar que estou usando o projeto Cordova. Nada mais é do que um template de um app android projeto para WebView

Comment: Como você fez para adicionar o Crosswalk ao projeto? O meu, mesmo achando que já está, quando roda pede pra baixar o crosswalk... Obrigado.